# How can I convert a .py script into a formal test?

Tags: pytest

I am new to python and my goal is to construct an automation environment in my department.
I am a QA Engineer and I would like to automate my functional Tests. I chose python for this purpose because i found out, during a research that I made, that python has all the modules that I need in order to fully automate my Functional Tests:

1. Selenium Webdriver
2. Control test/measurement devices with SCPI
3. Telnet or SSH my devices
4. SNMP

I have started my work by writing short verification tests. I wanted to see that i am able to automate my functional tests according to the list above.

I have some .py files that are actually tests actually tests and I would like to know:

1. Can I convert them into pytest ?
2. If I manage to run my automated functions (test) by running .py scripts why should I work with pytest ?

Comment: What is the actual format of your tests ? Do you use unittest ? You should use pytest because of https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/contents.html

Comment: I used simple py format. Meaning, I have functions and main() and I sometimes loop them in order to repeat a certain test several times. I do not use any testing framework. Is it recommended to keep coding in this format ? Why should I work with any testing framework ?

Comment: I am calling these .py scripts tests because they actually imitate my test cases and by writing results to files I also have some sort of reports. Later on when I will invest some more time in development I will have lots of tests (several hundreds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The short answer is "yes", it's easy to use pytests for existing tests. I'll explain below.
2. pytest makes it easy to collect your tests, run your tests, and provide output about your test run.

Fundamentally a test is some executable code that verifies some system behavior and raises an assertion exception when that behavior doesn't match expectations.

pytest can help you with your test suite:

- It provides a "test collector", a utility to find code that looks like tests, and to have you specify which tests you want to run, etc.
- It provides a "test runner", an execution framework to run your tests, gather results, and report on those results.
- It also provides a powerful concept of ["fixtures"](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html), which allow you to decouple test setup from the behavior being verified.

To answer your first question more specifically: either name your test files, functions, and classes according to the defaults (here's pytest's [documentation on how it collects tests by default](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#test-discovery)), or you can [change the defaults](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/pythoncollection.html). By default, basically have your test directories start with `test_`, classes start with `Test`, and functions start with `test_`. It's heavily customizable too.

Comment: So, generally speaking, I can keep on writing my Python scripts and run them (without using py.test yet) and in the future I will be able to run the same scripts through py.test ?

Comment: Yes that's right. Almost all test-shaped code can be run using pytest.

Comment: By the way, how is it actually done ? Do I need to Import my scripts into a new script with a "test_" extension ? Are you familiar with a guide or examples that would direct me ?

Comment: If your test files are in a "foo" directory, for example, you would run `pytest foo`. You may need to change the defaults of what's collected, if your tests aren't named with "test_". Tell me if these docs answer your question: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/pythoncollection.html#changing-naming-conventions

Comment: I am still confused. All the examples that I saw till now didn't deal with Functional Test like I have. The examples were simple and mostly dealt with Unit-tests. I still don't see how can I use py.test tu run the same .py scripts. The .py scripts that I am talking about are more or less Test Cases. They include procedures which are Test Steps and the main() part collects and orders them into a Test Case

Comment: You can either 1) rename the "main()" function in all your files to being with "test_", or 2) you can change what pytest considers a test function so that it collects "main()" functions as tests.

Comment: And then will I also need to add assertions ? What about monitoring the test steps "results", is it possible to have them too ?

Comment: @MosheS. Yes, your code will need to raise AssertionError or a subclass of AssertionError on failure. I'm not sure what you mean by monitoring the results -- you can print to stdout or stderr and pytest has options to show that output.